# Envelopes:listStatusChanges does not respect order_by parameter

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use the api `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes` with the following parameters;

- from_date
- to_date
- start_position
- order (asc)
- order_by ('created')

Example api call

```
{{baseURL}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{docusign-accountId}}/envelopes?from_date=2019-09-01T00:00:07.2430000Z&to_date=2020-03-25T01:01:07.2430000Z&start_position=0&count=1000&order=asc&order_by=created
```

Here I was expecting the response to be all envelopes that had status changes between the time range [from_data, to_date] **ordered by their created time in ascending order**.

However, I don't see the order_by field has any effect on the response. The envelopes that I am receiving are still ordered by statusChangedDateTime value (ascending order).

But, if I include another parameter to the api call

- from_to_status = 'created'

The response includes envelopes in the ascending order of their created time.

Please let me know if this is actually a bug and order_by field is not being respected currently, Or it's a limitation that **order_by = created** can only work with **from_to_status = created**. Or please let me know in case I am doing something wrong in using it properly.

Comment: can you add the full URL you're calling, how exactly it is set up?

Comment: @InbarGazit added the sample of api call I am making.

Comment: this URL is v2 and 2.1, can you change it to 2.1 and try again?

Answer (score 0):

You started by talking about 2.1 and then used 2.0. 
Your URL should be modified to use the 2.1 version of the API:

```
{{baseURL}}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{docusign-accountId}}/envelopes?from_date=2019-09-01T00:00:07.2430000Z&to_date=2020-03-25T01:01:07.2430000Z&start_position=0&count=1000&order=asc&order_by=created
```